# How to add a DOI field in book type reference in zotero?

Tags: bibtex, doi, zotero

I want to add a book reference with DOI in zotero. But I found no DOI field in book type items. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Uhm, I don't know how to do it in Zotero, perhaps you should ask on [its own site](https://forums.zotero.org/categories/). I also don't know if `bibtex` can handle a DOI field, but `biblatex` does. You should check the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for learn to import your references from Zotero and use the DOI field.

Comment: @Aradnix Thank you! I did as you said. Post on zotero forum. They said this feature is currently unavailable and will be developed with 6 months or so. So how can I close this question now?

Comment: For reference, here's the thread on the Zotero forums: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/40862/how-to-add-a-doi-field-in-book-type-reference-in-zotero/#Item_8

Answer (score 5):

At [support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/articles/723677-adding-new-variables-to-my-citation-style](http://support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/articles/723677-adding-new-variables-to-my-citation-style) the problem of unsupported fields in Mendeley Desktop is addressed.

The workaround explained there also works for Zotero: Add a DOI to a Zotero item of the type "book", for instance, by putting the line

```
{:DOI:10.1037/11019-008}
```

somewhere in the "extra" field. It will then beautifully make its way into the citation of the item.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if Zotero can't handle a DOI filed for some reason by now that isn't a problem if you use `biblatex` with `biber`. I insist that you *must* read the [package documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), is very extensive, I know, but it's enough if you review Chapters 2 and 3 and Appendix A4.

Since there is no a MEW, we suppose the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[options]{class}
\usepackage[options]{package}
\usepackage{package}
    .
    .
    .
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,   % as biber is the backend by default we don't need to specify it
style=numeric,   % Citation style, you can specify the style you use. In the CTAN there are many options additional to the standard styles from the package.
natbib=false,    % Allows aliases for natbib citation. E.g. \citet if needed.
backref=true,   % Adds a link from the bibliography to the paper
url=false,       % true if you need or want to add an url to your reference
isbn=false,      % true if you need to print a isbn/issn/isrn number
doi=true         % true if you need to print the doi key.
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=zoterordfxml]{mybibliography.bib} % bibliography database file with extension.
\begin{document}
    .
    .
    .
\printbibliography[options] % Usually you add this at the end of the document.
\end{document}
```

The other option if the `zoteroxml` fails is to export from Zotero to a `*.bib` file
Notice that for this trick works you need to use `biber` as backend, `bibtex` and `bibtex8` don't work. Also, the support for Zotero is experimental at this point yet. I'm seeing that Zotero 4 (standalone) is able to export your files not only into `bibtex` but also into `biblatex`, and perhaps this would be the best choice: export your references and later in a LaTeX editor or in JabRef you can fix any problem you'll find, and also fill the DOI field you need.

Answer (score 0):

Zotoro automatically adds the DOI is it is available. If not you have to add it manually.

You can then export your bibliography to `BibLaTeX` (or `BibTeX`)
Then use  `BibLaTeX` to generate the bibliography.

This is my setup.

```
\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex,   % uses BibTeX add backend=biber if you export to BibLaTex
style=authoryear, % Citation style
natbib=true,      % Allows for natbib citation. E.g. \citet and 
backref=true,     % Adds a link from the bibliography to the paper
url=false, isbn=false, doi=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{library.bib} %bibliograhy source
```

Then where you want your bibliography printed add

```
\printbibliography
```

Comment: Thank you. I have asked the same question on zotero forum. They said zotero currently doesn't support DOI field in book type.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. Did not see if was a problem specific to books.